# Excel VBA that loops through all sheets and changes the sheet color

Tags: vba, excel

I was hoping to find an excel vba that will loop through all sheets in a workbook and change the sheet color in the below order.
3, 5, 6, 12, 3, 5, 6, 12, 3, 5, 6, 12 ect repeating the pattern until it runs out of sheets.
The below code work to change them on a random color but I need the above pattern.

```
Sub sbColorAllSheetTab()
'Declaration
Dim iCntr, sht
'This will hold the colorIndex number
iCntr = 2
'looping throgh the all the sheets of the workbook
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
iCntr = iCntr + 1
'Applying the colors to Sheet tabs
sht.Tab.ColorIndex = iCntr
Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be great! ty!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub sbColorAllSheetTab()

    Dim iCntr, sht, arrColors, numColors

    arrColors = Array(3, 5, 6, 12) '<< array of color indexes

    iCntr = 0
    numColors = UBound(arrColors) + 1 '<< how many colors?

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Tab.ColorIndex = arrColors((iCntr Mod 4)) '<< use Mod to cycle color
        iCntr = iCntr + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: oops the twin thinking!!

Comment: same here - a few seconds apart!

Comment: Hello,

Thanks everyone for the quick response! the first one worked perfect!

Comment: Question: this works if the macro is in the same workbook, but when I try to run it on another workbook (ex: I have a macro sheet and a report) it only changes the macro sheet not the report?

Comment: ThisWorkbook is the file containing the macro - change that to ActiveWorkbook if you want to operate on whichever workbook is active

Answer (score 2):

Use an array and index through it

```
Sub sbColorAllSheetTab()
    Dim iCntr As Long, sht As Worksheet, arr
    arr = Array(3, 5, 6, 12, ...) ' any sequence

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Tab.ColorIndex = arr(iCntr)
        iCntr = (iCntr + 1) Mod (UBound(arr) + 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the brave downvoter, you should get a life ;)

Comment: @TimWilliams No worries bro, thanks anyway. Be sure I never had any doubt, I even almost "know" the brave guy :). I dont mind being downvoted when I commit mistakes, but when there's none....

Comment: @ A.S.H you are a 10K user. So you can always delete your post, and see if that persons rep goes up by 1. A certain long-term user here frequently gives me a batch of downvotes if I post to the same threads as he does.

Comment: @brettdj thanks for the tip. I will think of that. Unfortunately we have to expect the existence of a few of such mentalities everywhere, even among the highly educated ones. But we can live with it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let me know what do you thing about this.

```
Sub sbColorAllSheetTab()
Dim shtMod As Byte
'looping throgh the all the sheets of the workbook
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    shtMod = sht.Index Mod 4
    Select Case shtMod
        Case 1
            sht.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
        Case 2
            sht.Tab.ColorIndex = 5
        Case 3
            sht.Tab.ColorIndex = 6
        Case 0
            sht.Tab.ColorIndex = 12
    End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I notice there's 2 downvotes with no comments.  It's courtesy to give a reason why, and in this case downvotes are not warranted. This works and answers OP's question. Even if it is not the 'best' answer, it is still a solution.